# How to add a mouse click/drag event in a circle of canvas. in HTML 5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drag-and-drop

Need to add a drag drop effect using java script in canvas.
example can be seen in following link
http://ypublisher.eu/ctrl.php/portal/sample?url=media/Math_module/index.htm

This is entirely a flash application

please see the blue circles with expressions with them. circles can be clicked and dragged. on dragging a line with arrow creates and can be attached with any of the other circle.

i need to make the same using HTML 5 and Java script
i have used canvas to display the blue circles
but not able to make a drag thing work.
can any body know how to add a drag event on the circle in canvas.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use some canvas frameworks, e.g. [LibCanvas](http://libcanvas.github.com/), there are a lot of examples of interactive shapes, including circles.

You can read article "[Creating a Framework For Canvas: Objects and Mouse](http://www.splashnology.com/article/creating-a-framework-for-canvas-objects-and-mouse/989/)" to know, how it works inside, but better is using public frameworks.